# Become nil Referring to YTPlayer from a different view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios10

I want to control the video player of the video view from the screen transition destination.

[image: I want to play a video by tapping the cell]

I want to play a video by tapping the cell

Try to

// Select(Tap) to cell

```
override func tableView(_ table: UITableView,didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

          let video = ViewController()

          video.playerView.playVideo()

    }
```

But fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image: Error]

Append:

I tried to use YTPlayer from https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

But I did not understand how to write in your code "YTPlayer".

YTPlayer doesn't have YTPlayer(exist YTPlayerView) and YTPlayerLayer.

My viewcontoller's code here

```
import UIKit
import youtube_ios_player_helper
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, YTPlayerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var playerView: YTPlayerView!

var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.playerView.delegate = self

    self.playerView.sizeToFit()



    let vars = ["playsinline": 1, "controls": 2, "showinfo": 0, "origin":"https://www.google.com"] as [String : Any]

    if self.appDelegate.selectMV == ""
    {
        print("Not Load",self.appDelegate.selectMV)
    }
    else
    {
        print("Load",self.appDelegate.selectMV)
        playerView.load(withVideoId: self.appDelegate.selectMV, playerVars: vars)
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {

        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

    }

    catch {

        print("")

    }


}

func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    playerView.playVideo()
}

func play() {
    print("Push! play")
    //Error playerView nil 
    playerView.load(withVideoId: self.appDelegate.selectMV)
    playerView.playVideo()
    }

}
```

Comment: I can provide you solution but still i am not getting the problem you are facing what exactly you want to do?? You want to play the video in different view or different frames.??? Please mention your problem from images i am enable to get your problem.

Comment: Thank JAck. Yes. I want to play the video in different view. I append my problem form image.

Comment: In different Views May be you have problem with memory issues.. Am I correct??

Comment: Please tell me your code replace YTPlayer. YTPlayer doesnt have YTPlayerLayer etc... https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Answer (score 0):

It's quit simple.. You need to code in didselect as you've done. But This kinds of code will never works here. You have to code like this in ViewDidLoad() or ViewWillAppear() First.

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath) as URL)
self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
self.playerLayer.frame = self.vview.bounds
```

Then In didSelect Only code for simply

```
Player.play()
```

If you want to change playerItem There simply code in didSelect Like this..

```
player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)))
```

It's for the single View. Try like this and if you need any help feel free to ask me.

Comment: OK. So in YTPlayer. If you want to play video. Try using touches Began Function applying on your view.